# Drools Validation of Products in a Product Catalog to ensure the right classification is chosen

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have a drools application, which has a product catalogue, products. Clients can buy any number of products from multiple classes. However, they can only purchase a  certain number from any given class.  Here is the structure of the ProductCatalog class.  It contains lists of products according to their classification.

```
class ProductCatalog {

  List<Product> classA =
  List<Product> classB =
  List<Product> classC =

  ... getters and setters
}
```

Next is the Product class which provides details of the products that a customer is allowed to order.

```
  class Product {
   String classification;
   String code;
   String name;
   String description;
   BigDecimal cost;
   ...getters and setters
  }
```

The final class is the Purchase class which contains all the products the customer has ordered. The purchases are bundled together, so there is no separation of the products in classifications in this object. There are a number of rules that determine how purchases can be made. Users can only bundle products they wish to purchase by following these rules. Here is the Purchase class.

```
  class Purchase {
    Customer details 
    List<Product> orders =
   ... getters and setters
  }
```

The purchasing strategy is similar to Cable television packages where you have to purchase certain options in some categories in order to get say HBO or the sports package.  The problem I am trying to solve requires providing validation to ensure that only the right package options are provided to the user when they make certain choices. I am stuck with using the ProductCatalog to determine whether the products in the Purchase object are in a certain class.

Here is roughly what I am thinking:

```
  rule Determine if a purchase is in classA

  when 
     $catalog: ProductCatalog ( )
     $purchases: Purchase()
     $prod: Product (  classification == $catalog..., code='XFEEEO222'....,  'PDX12224') from $purchases.orders

then
    insert($prod)
```

I want to first verify that they have selected a product from classA before they can proceed to the other product classifications. I don't know how to use the ProductCatalog to determine the classification from the products in the purchases.  I would be very grateful if someone could direct me how to accomplish that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know whether the `Purchase` contains at least 1 `Product` of classA, then you can try something along these lines:

```
 rule Determine if a purchase is in classA

  when 
     $catalog: ProductCatalog ( )
     $purchases: Purchase()
     exists Product (this in $catalog.classA) from $purchases.orders

then

end
```

Note that in the previous rule, you can't have a reference to the `Product` that caused the activation. If you need to have a reference to the `Product/s` in your RHS, then you can try something like this:

```
 rule Determine if a purchase is in classA

  when 
     $catalog: ProductCatalog ( )
     $purchases: Purchase()
     $aProducts: List (size > 0) from collect (
        Product(this in $catalog.classA) from $purchases.orders
     )
then

end
```

Hope it helps,

end